# Python Selenium Merge Multiple Instances in One Icon

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

All I want to do is open multiple (and independent) selenium browsers, but each time I create a new one, a new chrome icon pops up on my taskbar. The problem is that, by creating more and more, the taskbar fills up with these chrome icons, which is disturbing. I tried running the browsers --headless--, but I also want to visually see what's on my browsers. Can I merge the icons into one (each and every one of them has to be independent) ? Is this possible?

Comment: What about adding new tabs in the same window?

Comment: I tried, but it's not what I'm looking for because they are not independent (they have the same ip no matter what)

Comment: Sorry, but can you tell me why you want to do this? Maybe i can give you an alternative solution...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by using `user-data-dir=` chrome option and attaching to every browser I create a different file like so:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir={your_wanted_path})
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path={chromedriver_path}, chrome_options=options)
```